# How to sort this list of lists and remove the empty ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list of lists.

```
list_code = [[], [], [{'CODE': '324113', 'X': '30909.560489999996'}], [], [],
            [{'CODE': '324108', 'X': '31006.29439'}], [], ]
```

I want to remove the empty lists and sort the non-empty ones according to `CODE` in ascending order. The desired result (list of dictionaries) will look something like this;

```
correct_code = [{'CODE': '324108', 'X': '30909.560489999996'},
                {'CODE': '324113', 'X': '31006.29439'}]
```

I am using python 3.7

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, but it would help if you showed some effort. If you can't make it work, go ahead and provide a [MCVE] for us to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
list_code = [[], [], [{'CODE': '324113', 'X': '30909.560489999996'}], [], [],             [{'CODE': '324108', 'X': '31006.29439'}], [], ]
 correct_code = []
 for i in list_code:
    if i:
        correct_code.append(i[0])
 correct_code.sort(key=lambda x: x['CODE'])
```

or

```
correct_code = [i[0] for i in list_code if i]
correct_code.sort(key=lambda x: x['CODE'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using the `sorted` method

Removing empty lists

```
new_list_code = []
for val in list_code:
    if len(val) > 0:
        new_list_code.append(*val)
```

Using `lambda` function to sort

```
result = sorted(new_list_code, key=lambda x: x[0]['CODE'])
```

Comment: `result = sorted(list_code, key=lambda x: x[0]['CODE'])` this code retrning  `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @LeoArad I have updated the code, please check now!

Comment: Stil the same only list_code = [val for val in list_code if len(val) > 0] is returning the correct answer but it's list of list `[[{'CODE': '324113', 'X': '30909.560489999996'}],
 [{'CODE': '324108', 'X': '31006.29439'}]]`

Comment: @LeoArad I tried with the content of OP's `list_code` and it is returning the expected answer

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating new lists like so;

```
list_code = [[], [], [{'CODE': '324113', 'X': '30909.560489999996'}], [], [], [{'CODE': '324108', 'X': '31006.29439'}], []]
temp_list_code = []
temp_dict_code = []
```

This function will store non empty lists in a temporary array;

```
def remove_empty():
    for x in list_code:
        if len(x) > 0:
            temp_list_code.append(x)
```

This will turn the lists of lists into a single list and sort;

```
def sort_dicts():
    for y in range(0, len(temp_list_code)):
        temp_dict_code.append(temp_list_code[y][y-1])
```

At this point, we have a list of dictionaries but it's not sorted yet

```
[{'CODE': '324113', 'X': '30909.560489999996'}, {'CODE': '324108', 'X': '31006.29439'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted([item[0] for item in a if item], key=lambda x: x['CODE'])
```

Comment: Short, elegant answer. Excellent!

Comment: Not exactly the right answer. The printed output is not a list of dictionaries, but a list of list of single dictionaries. You can print out the answer and check. It does look elegant.